# Prove that the Laplacian of the integral of a certain function is $0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function. Define
$$g(x,y)=\int_a^b\frac{yf(t)}{(x-t)^2+y^2}dt$$
Show that $\nabla^2g=0$

Comment: Are you missing a $y$ on the numerator?

Comment: Yes, I am. I have fixed it. How could you tell?

Comment: This is essentially the Poisson extension: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel